# Add .js files at the bottom of the page from User Control

Tags: asp.net, performance, user-controls, webforms

I have a user control on my web forms app and I need to reference a js file on the user control.

I would like to add this js file at the bottom of the output html page but I don't know how to do it from User Control.

I have following script references on my master page;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/1.7/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and they are staying just after the `</body>` tag at the bottom. I'm using my user control like below on a web form page;

```
<userControl:SearchEngine ID="SearchEngine" runat="server"></userControl:SearchEngine>
```

and from this user control, I would like to add the a js at the bottom of the outputted html markup after the 3rd js file which you can see above.

any idea?

Comment: So your User Control exposes a JS script and you want to add this script to some HTML? Where is the HTML being outputted from?

Comment: @keyboardP from an web form page. (AKA .aspx page) I'll edit my qu a little bit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using RegisterClientStartUpScript() method to inject it at the end of the page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx#aspnet-injectclientsidesc_topic2

Comment: ok, it really helped. I found a similar solution on stackoverflow and it suggests to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method. is there a difference? the following code worked perfectly fine.         `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "SuggestionSearch",
                String.Format("<script src='{0}' type='text/javascript'></script>", ResolveUrl("~/Secure/Shared/SuggestionSearch.js")), false);`

Comment: RegisterClientStartUpScript is a page method; only use ScriptManager if you're working with AJAX (AFAIK) :)

Comment: @IrishChieftain yeah, I am using AJAX Control Toolkit as well. so it is legit to use it, right? seems like working on my machine.

Comment: Then that's the correct way for you :) Out of curiosity, check markup and see if it's being rendered just before the closing </form> tag?

Comment: @IrishChieftain yeah, I already did that it is. but after that there are some js content which belongs to AjaxControltoolkit.

Comment: That's all good, especially for SEO because the bots won't have to crawl though it at the top of the page :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a literal control at the bottom and set its text property with the content of the javascript file.